# Set random value from set

Tags: postgresql, random

I need to put some random values into database, but I don't want to end up with completely randomized text (like 7hfg43d3). Instead I would like to randomly pick one of values supplied by myself.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[Nice idea.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/55364/3684) I suggest two minor simplifications:

```
('{Foo,Bar,Poo}'::text[])[ceil(random()*3)]
```

- Simpler syntax using an **array literal** (`'{Foo,Bar,Poo}'::text[]`)
  Shortens the string for longer lists.
  Additional benefit: explicit type declaration works for any type, not just for `text`. Your original idea happens to output `text`, because that's the default type for string literals.
- Use [`ceil()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE) instead of `floor() + 1`. Same result.

OK, theoretically, the lower bound could be 0 precisely, as hinted in [your comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55363/set-random-value-from-set/55401#comment99573_55401), since `random()` produces ([quoting the manual here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE)):

> random value in the range 0.0 <= x < 1.0

However, I have never seen that happen. Run a couple of million tests:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM   generate_series(1,1000000)
WHERE  ceil(random())::int = 0;
```

[**-> SQLfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/633)

To be perfectly safe, though, you can use Postgres custom array subscripts and still avoid the extra addition:

```
('[0:2]={Foo,Bar,Poo}'::text[])[floor(random()*3)]
```

See:

- [Normalize array subscripts for 1-dimensional array so they start with 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12011569/939860)
- [Why does PostgreSQL allow querying for array[0] even though it uses 1-based arrays?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117670/why-does-postgresql-allow-querying-for-array0-even-though-it-uses-1-based-arra/117678#117678)

Better yet, use [`trunc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE), [that's a bit faster.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15284333/939860)

```
('[0:2]={Foo,Bar,Poo}'::text[])[trunc(random()*3)]
```

Comment: ceil(0) == floor(0) + 1?

Comment: @korda: I added more, addressing that.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter don't you think that ```ceil(random())::int``` will always give you 1 so you won't be able check if it will ever return 0?

Comment: @aki92: `ceil(0.0)` wouldn't, that's the point. OTOH: for the purpose of this test we might simplify: `WHERE  random() = 0.0`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter oh true, sorry just missed that thing.

Answer (score 9):

I came up with idea to use Arrays to accomplish this:

```
(ARRAY['Foo','Bar','Poo'])[floor(random()*3)+1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on this idea, I've created a function that was quite useful for me:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION random_choice(
    choices text[]
)
RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE
    size_ int;
BEGIN
    size_ = array_length(choices, 1);
    RETURN (choices)[floor(random()*size_)+1];
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Usage examples:

- `SELECT random_choice(array['h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']) as random_char;`
- `SELECT random_choice((SELECT array_agg(name) FROM pets)) AS pet_name;`

Comment: You can morph this function into a function with [variadic](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS) parameter which I personally find more user friendly.