# Why does PostgreSQL allow querying for array[0] even though it uses 1-based arrays?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, array

I have been playing with arrays in one of my PostgreSQL databases.

I have created a table with a geometry array with at least one element:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_arrays (
    polygons geometry(Polygon,4326)[],
    CONSTRAINT non_empty_polygons_chk 
        CHECK ((COALESCE(array_length(polygons, 1), 0) <> 0))
);
```

I have added a few rows, and queried the table for the first element in each geometry array:

```sql
SELECT polygons[0] FROM test_arrays;
```

To my surprise, I got a list of empty rows!

After some research, it turns out that [PostgreSQL arrays are one-based](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html):

> The array subscript numbers are written within square brackets. By default PostgreSQL uses a one-based numbering convention for arrays, that is, an array of n elements starts with array[1] and ends with array[n].

So `SELECT polygons[0] FROM test_arrays;` worked and returned the first `polygon` of each row.

If PostgreSQL uses a one-based numbering convention, why is querying the 0-th element allowed, and does the result have any meaning?

Comment: Read that page to the end: "*Also, null is returned if a subscript is outside the array bounds (this case does not raise an error)*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name True and thank-you. I guess that the this design principle is intended to stop queries for raising errors and ending transactions due to index mismatches.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Postgres arrays are 1-based by default. And in typical applications it's best to stick with the default. But the syntax allows to start with ***any*** `integer` number. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-MODIFYING)

> Subscripted assignment allows creation of arrays that do not use
> one-based subscripts. For example one might assign to `myarray[-2:7]` to
> create an array with subscript values from -2 to 7.

Examples:

```
SELECT ('[0:2]={1,2,3}'::int[])[0];    --> 1
SELECT ('[-7:-5]={1,2,3}'::int[])[-6]; --> 2
```

You can query *any* index of an array, if it does not exist you get `NULL`.

Related:

- [Normalize array subscripts for 1-dimensional array so they start with 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12011569/939860)